# Dealing with multiple bookmarks in windows workflow 4.5

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I am just starting with windows workflow 4.5. I am creating a simple console app. I am asking the user for data along the way. I followed some tutorials and I created some activities which ask the user for different data. Those Activities create bookMarks. How do I handle these multiple bookmarks in my host program. The tutorial had a loop and seemed to assumed that there would only be one bookmark. which looks like

```
    WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { syncEvent, idleEvent };
    while (WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles) != 0)
    {
        bool needsReview = false;
        while (!needsReview)
        {
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            Boolean review;
            if (response == "y")
            {
                needsReview = true;
                review = true;
                wfApp.ResumeBookmark("Review", review);
            }
            else if (response == "n")
            {
                needsReview = true;
                review = false;
                wfApp.ResumeBookmark("Review", review);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter 'y' or 'n'");
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I properly write this when I am dealing with many prompts to the user that have to handle information in different ways and resume different bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to this. There is a GetBookmarks property in the WorkflowApplication object. In my simple Activity which has two bookmarks, GetBookmarks only contains the single bookmark which I need each time the Activity pauses.

Given it is a Collection (a `ReadonlyCollection(Of Hosting.BookmarkInfo)` to be precise), there may be circumstances where it does contain more than one item, guessing something like parallel branches.

Either way, you can do an if-then-else or switch to interrogate this and return all correct info.

For example:

`Hosting.BookmarkInfo ThisBookmark = CurrentBookmarks.First;`

`string InputName = Console.ReadLine;`

`wfApp.ResumeBookmark(ThisBookmark.BookmarkName, InputName);`

Obviously adjusting the above for input types etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you are developing a console application, then it is a desktop application. So I assume there is one user, and one workflow working at a time. Is it possible that the workflow is stopped at different bookmarks? Am not sure what you mean in real life.

On any ways the bookmark name is a way to identify the different bookmarks, and you can also keep the bookmark object when you create one

```
Bookmark bookmark = wfApp.CreateBookmark("aasdasd");
```